# Android Camera with Surfaceview

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to built my own camera app in android including the following options pinch to zoom and autofocus without using camera intent. I already gone through some samples from Git hub but I couldn't make use of them.So, I decided to start learning Camera API from Google developers. Here I need a complete steps to develop my app and what to learn like camera,  surface view and anything else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done what you want to be done recently.

For android, there are 2 camera APIs

- [the camera api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)
- and [the camera2 api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

camera api is deprecated on android api 21. starting from android api 21, you have to use camera2 api. so you have to learn both of them.

- Camera api brother with SurfaceView.
- Camera2 api brother with TextureView.

Camera2 api is quit alot different from Camera api, and also is much more complicated than Camera api.

You may want to take a look at my project [SimpleCameraView](https://github.com/DanielShum/SimpleCameraView), it is much clear than other projects. I just created this repository yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Things to Need to Learn to Build Custom Camera APP

- Setting Camera,FlashLight and FILE_STORAGE Permissions in Manifest
- SurfaceView and How to Use it.
- Manual Control of Flash Light.
- Lazy Loader for Displaying Images Taken without Memory Leaking.

And you can go through this for Sample : [Build Custom Camera](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/how-to-make-a-custom-camera-ion-android/)

Comment: Can you help to solve below features which i was trying for past two days that pinch to zoom and tap on focus

Comment: I have found solution for my pinch zoom option using onTouchEvent() and scaleGestureEvent